# OpenCV Point Undistortion

Tags: python, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi, distortion

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 with the official 5MP camera. I have calibrated the camera using OpenCV 3.2.0. I am coding in Python 3.4.2 (I know it's not the latest version, but recompiling OpenCV for a newer version is out of the question).

My question is, if I have a point within a square relative to the camera, and I have the points of all 4 corners of the square relative to the camera (not exactly a square because it may be rotated and moved slightly), how do I find that point relative to the square?

For example, if the top-left corner of the square was (10, 20), and the original point was a bit to the right and down, maybe (21, 33), then the final point might be something like (15, 18).

Basing this result on 1 corner (and just subtracting the input point and the corner) is not enough because the image may be scaled. Basing it on 2 opposite corners (assuming that the square is perfectly square and not rotated) is not enough because the image may be rotated. In theory, 3 should be enough if I calibrated the camera correctly (and made a perfect square or rectangle), but 4 is better to be totally sure.

The problem is that I do not how to remap the point on the image to the point on the square. How should I do that?

Example (sorry for low quality):

[image: Checkerboard]
[image: Checkerboard with input points: [(163, 17) -> (0, 0), (294, 50) -> (5, 0), (313, 273) -> (5, 8), and (145, 275) -> (0, 8)], output point: (257, 149) -> (3.5, 4)]

Given the 4 red camera and output points and the green camera point, how do I find the green output point?

Answer (score 0):

Just after writing (I swear I had *just finished writing*), I came upon the function: [`cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga8c1ae0e3589a9d77fffc962c49b22043). Here's how it would be used for the example:

```py
rows = 5
columns = 8
inputs = [(163, 17), (294, 50), (313, 273), (145, 275)]
outputs = [(0, 0), (5, 0), (5, 8), (0, 8)]

transform_matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(inputs, outputs)

def transform(point):
    global transform_matrix
    return cv2.perspectiveTransform(point, transform_matrix)
```